# Importing from Maven or Jcenter fails (Jitpack works)

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter, jitpack

I've a [lint lib](https://github.com/GuilhE/AndroidStyling-LintRules) that fails to import throwing:

```
> Failed to resolve: AndroidStyling-LintRules:checks:unspecified
> Affected Modules: app
```

So I tested running `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` and this was thrown:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':styling-lint:publishAndroidPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'android' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Invalid publication 'android': artifact file does not exist: '.../styling-lint/build/outputs/aar/styling-lint-release.aar'
```

I found what was missing so after fixing it by adding `builtBy`:

```
artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar") {
    builtBy(tasks.getByName("assemble"))
}
```

`publishToMavenLocal` builds successfully and I can use `mavenLocal()` to import and it works.
Unfortunately, importing from remote still fails with the same output...

Jitpack import works:
[image]

What's happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For no apparent reason it started to work  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`